# What does "expression with associated function" mean?

Tags: functions, polynomials

I have happened upon the following definition of a polynomial:

> Recall that a polynomial in a single variable is an expression that has an associated function. The polynomial expression $p(x)=a_d x^d+a_{d-1} x^{d-1}+\cdots+a_1 x+a_0$.

What is meant by "expression that has an associated function" here? Do they mean that the expression is $p(x)=a_d x^d+a_{d-1} x^{d-1}+\cdots+a_1 x+a_0$, and that this always comes associated with some function, not stand-alone, which is in this case $p$? And they mean by expression to refer explicitly to the polynomial expression they subsequently define?

Comment: You have an element of the ring $R[x]$ and you associate it with a function $S\to S$ where $R\leqslant S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A polynomial is an **expression** of a special form: it's a sum of a finite number of terms where each term is on the form $ax^k.$ Here the variable $x$ is just a symbol; it shouldn't be thought of as a number. Example: $p(x)=x^2+3.$

The **function** associated with the polynomial is a map taking a number and inserting that in place of the variable: $x\mapsto p(x),$ e.g. $0\mapsto 3,$ $1\mapsto 4,$ $2\mapsto 7.$